# Angular ng-repeat, image hover not working

Tags: angularjs

I'm having a bit of trouble working out why my images aren't rendering properly inside of an ng-repeat with an ng-init, ng-mousover and ng-mouseout.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in product.items">
    <div ng-init="imgsrc='{{item.image01}}'" 
         ng-mouseover="imgsrc='{{item.image02}}'" 
         ng-mouseout="imgsrc='{{item.image01}}'">
        <img ng-src="{{imgsrc}}" />
    </div>
</div>
```

The correct paths are rendering inside of ng-init, ng-mouseover and ng-mouseout, but the `<img>` tag is only updating with {{item.image01}} and {{item.image02}} instead of the actual image paths.

What am I missing here?

Comment: `ng-mouseover="imgsrc=item.image02"`

Comment: Check my answer. Or if you want to stick with your solution try the comment from Alon or remove the single quotes.

Comment: After finding the problem, really think about switching this task to CSS. This is such an overkill

Comment: @AlonEitan - that was it.

Comment: @azerafati - the idea behind this method is to make sure there is only one image loaded at a time. I'm not aware of a CSS method that can make this work. I'm intrigued, though. Can you explain?

Comment: you mean there is only one image Shown at a time, right?

Comment: @azerafati - correct - this is for a large catalog of products, loading ~24 at a time - each image ~50KB lets say. We want to minimize overhead, so loading 24x50kb is much more attractive than 24x100kb(two versions of the image)

Comment: I've also posted the solution in the original question. Thanks for posting below, @azerafati

Comment: @azerafati - I see where you're coming from, though. We may evaluate whether or not we can get away with loading both images at the same time instead of using this method. Our images are all approx. 30-40kb.

Comment: If @azerafati's answer is the correct, then you need to mark it as the correct one by checking the checkmark next to it. http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove the braces, for assigning values to variables you don't need them inside `ng-init`.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in product.items">
    <div ng-init="imgsrc=item.image01" 
         ng-mouseover="imgsrc=item.image02" 
         ng-mouseout="imgsrc=item.image01">
        <img ng-src="{{imgsrc}}" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's fine to assign a value with `ng-init`, but `ng-moseouver` and `ng-mouseout` don't work the same.

Try to create a function and pass it to them:

```
ng-mouseover="handleMouseover()" 
ng-mouseout="handleMouseout()"
```

Then update the value of your variable inside of the methods accordingly.